# How can I create a new document in mongo db without using Forms?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript

I want to create a new document in a mongo db collection without getting any information from the user. I am using MEAN fullstack combined with ionic 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quit sure if I got your question but you can use any GUI software for dealing with mongodb such as [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/) or [compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass).

And If you want to test an API or make a request without a form you could use something like postman or insomnia

Comment: Yes, i get your point there. However that is not what i want to do, I am trying to create a new document  from my page.ts file. Meaning that i want to input the data that goes into the document myself.

Comment: you have to import mongodb driver package or use ODM library  like mongoose

this allows you to connect to the mongodb and execute task

Comment: Yes, i did that. Actually i am already using GET to retrieve the data from a different collection and it works fine. I will try postman, hopefully it can help.

Comment: ok, let me know I It worked and please upvote my answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: Nope, did not work. I think i have a problem with my server but i do not know where it is :(